Next Auth: localhost code redirecting me to domain or production URL on login
I deployed my app but when I went back to localhost to continue with the development, when I tired to login by google it redirected me to the URL in production.
I have tried to change the redirect URI y google console but it does not work.

After trying a lot of things in https://console.cloud.google.com/. You just need to change the environment variables NEXTAUTH_URL in .env to http://localhost:3000 with the port that you are using.
In one time I changed the value of this environment variable to the production URL. This keeps redirecting me to production, so when I change to local host it works.
